# Return value from nested private function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, methods, return

The following code works well in most cases *except* when I'm trying to return a value from the private function. How can I get the return value from private without exposing the private function ?

```
var _private = function() {    
  return 'hello' ;    
},
public = function() {
  _private();
};
```

Comment: `return _private();`

Comment: `return _private();`

Comment: What are you doing in `_private()` function? Clearly this is pseudo code.

Comment: `var result = _private(); return result; ` But this is about the same as comments above

Comment: @rick that would essentially expose _private();

Comment: @master00 the _private() function is not really private anyway in this case

Comment: Well if you're referring to the fact that I intentionally left out the closure that may be true. But, I figured it would be assumed that this would be part of a closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
var _private = function() {    
  return 'hello' ;    
},
public = function() {
  return _private();
};
```

Comment: Rory beat you to it but this is indeed the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the `return` statement
`return _private()`

```js
var _private = function() {    
  return 'hello' ;    
},
public = function() {
  return _private();
};

console.log(public());
console.log(_private());
```

**NOTE:** your *private* function is not very private. As you can see in the above snippet. The function is accessible

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has no private functions natively, You will need to use a closure to create a privately accessible scope for you `_private` function. Here is a quick example.

```js
var public = (function(){ 

  var _private = function() {    
    return 'hello' ;    
  }
  
  return function() {
    return _private();
  }
   
})()

console.log(
  public(),
  typeof _private === 'undefined'
)
```